# Upload external dependencies to local maven repository

Tags: android, maven, gradle, publish

I try to use local publishing for my sdk, then compile it in main app project.

So the apply :

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
```

with the command `./gradlew publishToMavenLocal`

But seems that external dependencies are not uploaded

[image]

So build errors appear

[image]

[full log link](https://gist.github.com/holysheep/28024b9b8e1a47fbbe147432b2293d02)

How to handle these external dependencies?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Publishing in Gradle will not publish transitive dependencies.** Otherwise once new artifact version will be published (e.g. Spring) you will also publish everything with it (e.g. log4j) which is already published and will fail.

**So if you want to compile your project, you have to specify both Maven Local (for your artifact) and Maven Central (for external artifacts) in `repositories{}` clause**:

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}
```